# How to using oracledataadapter with transaction?

Tags: c#, oracle, transactions

I use a method to gettable using a Select statiments.When i use a select statiment using a link database i got error (ORA-01453 SET TRANSATION must be first statement of transation.)

I know solition but i cant use Transaction methot with Oracledataadapter.

I want to use Commit() ... Rollback().

This is my code:

```
private System.Data.DataTable GetDataTable_(string SqlStatement, bool fromProcCall)
        {

            OracleConnection Con = new OracleConnection();
            try
            {
                Con = Connection();
                OpenConnection(Con, fromProcCall);

                //-----------------------------------------
                DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
                //-----------------------------------------
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter(SqlStatement, Con);                
                sda.Fill(ds, "tbl1");
                //-----------------------------------------
                if (!fromProcCall)
                    DurationOfIfsAction = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).Milliseconds;
                else
                    DurationOfFirstIfsAction = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).Milliseconds;
                //-----------------------------------------

                CloseConnection(Con);
                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Con != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        CloseConnection(Con);
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }
                }
                throw new Exception("ERROR[" + ex.Message + "]");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you could do something like this:

```
oraConn = new OracleConnection("CONNECTION STRING");
oraConn.Open();

//Command with transaction
OracleCommand oraCom = oraConn.CreateCommand();
oraCom.CommandText = "INSERT QUERY";
oraCom.Transaction = oraCom.Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

//Execute
if (oraCom.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
      oraCom.Connection.Open();
}

oraCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Commit / Rollback
oraCom.Transaction.Commit(); // or oraCom.Transaction.Rollback();
```

To use this with DataAdapter, the concept is the same: Create the transaction setting the `DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Transaction` and then you can control with `Commit()` and `Rollback()`.